# Is it possible to split a ul list li item in two equal parts when words overflow?

Tags: css

I have a list and what happens is this:

short item------------------------| (end of ul div)

short item
short item
really really really really long
item

is it possible to make the width of the li shrink to fit two lines or to make the li break exactly in two? like so:

really really really
really long item

so that it looks more even? or is that impossible with css?

EDIT:

It's a regular ul li list (generated by the site), single level. Nothing special. I just don't like the effect because they (the li's) have a different color than the div that contains the list, so each li has a box that fits it, and the really long item's box looks off when there's just one or two overflowing words.

I guess I'll have to find a way to do it with jquery or something. Setting a width or a max-width doesn't help, there already is one and even longer items would create an unnecesary number of lines.

Comment: Show us your code (HTML and CSS)...

Comment: a li always breaks into a new line by default, so it's evident there's something else, like some extra code or special condition we don't know. Seeing your code would help a lot

Comment: It's just a regular ul li list inside a div that's generated (I don't have control over the actual list's content). I just don't like how it looks, thought there might be some css property I hadn't learned. Guess I'll have to see if I can do something about it with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting a width on the UL so it contains the Li

here is a tool to let you play with css i tried it here and seems to narrow down all the li's

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_float

```
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100px;
}

li {
  float: right;

}

a {
display: block;
width: 60px;
background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that breaking `li` into 2 equal parts is possible with only css, but you can set `max-width` property to `li` it will limit the width of your list.

**html:**

```
<ul>
    <li>short item</li>
    <li>short item</li>
    <li>short item</li>
    <li>really really really really long item</li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
li {
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/557t6p0k/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `width=10%`  your `<ul> tag` like `<ul="10%"><ul/ul>` and play around with the number a little bit